# iOS show callout instead of annotation

Tags: ios, ios7, annotations, mapkit

Is there an easy way how can I set callout as annotation? I know I could make annotation which could look like default callout but I am looking for better solution? Is existing some easier solution? And if not then anyone has code which exactly fits default callout? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best project for this is probably http://github.com/nfarina/calloutview